# Set the child view at the TopLeft and BottomRight in a viewgroup

Tags: android, layout, view, viewgroup

In my application I have the layout like this:

1) The main view can be moved and dragged.

2) Some controllers can be added to inside the main view. And their position can be set to `TopLeft` or something else. The `TopLeft` here means relative  to the main view.(See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqJ3n.jpg))

Now I tried to implement this by extending the `ViewGroup`, and the `main View` and the `controllers` are all extends from `View`.

This is what I have done now:

```
class MyViewContainer extends ViewGroups{
   @Override
   public void onLayout(boolean changed,int l,int t,int b, int r){

      for(int i=0,len=getChildCounts,i<len;i++){
        View v=getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof MainView){
           v.layout(l,t,b,r);
        }
        else if(v instanceof MyController){
          //here do not now know how to layout the childs according to their position
        }
      }
   }
}
abstract MyController extends View{
}
class ZoomController extends MyController{
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c){

    }
}
class AnotherController extends MyController{
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c){

    }
}
class MainView extends View{
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c){

    }
}
```

As you can see, I have no idea to layout the `MyControllers`. Since I do not exactly know the width and height of the `controller`. Beacuse the size of  controllers is depended on how it is being drawn.

How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. For this to work, the master view has to come before the controllers.

```
class MyViewContainer extends ViewGroups{
    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed,int l,int t,int b, int r){
        View masterView = null;
        for(int i=0,len=getChildCounts,i<len;i++){
            View v=getChildAt(i);
            if(v instanceof MainView){
                masterView = v;
                v.layout(l,t,b,r);
            }
            else if(v instanceof MyController){
                // Layout your views here.
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                if (masterView != null && topLeft) {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, masterView.getId());
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, masterView.getId());
                }
                if (masterView != null && bottomRight) {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, masterView.getId());
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, masterView.getId());
                }
                v.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
    }
}
```